# Map JSON APi-style "type" attribute to object classes with RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit, json-api

I am trying to fetch data from a REST API conforming to the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org) standard using the great RestKit framework.

All the RestKit examples assumed the object type to be specified as an object key.
Example for an `article`-object:

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "title": "RestKit Object Mapping Intro",
      "author": "Blake Watters",
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Now what I want is to map a json-response like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "articles",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!",
        "author": "Steve Klabnik et al."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can this be mapped with RestKit? If yes, how?

Comment: That depends what you want to map it to, and how many different types there are. Give details.